# Apache Shiro: Prevent method access unless @RequiresPermission is applied

Tags: shiro

I have a number of Spring RestControllers. While most of the methods have @RequiresPermission, some of them do not have the annotation.

I am looking for a way to negatively bias the checks so that the method cannot be invoked unless there is a @RequiresPermission annotation on the method.

I was looking at applying a class level @RequiresPermission that turns off access and then the method level annotations will enable access to those subjects with the specified access.

Or is there a way I can do this using Spring AOP (class with @Aspect) ?